# How to create and read values from a button slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I am trying to read a true/false value from a button slider. Here are my codes

```
<select name="slide-1" id="slide-1">
    <option value="true">On</option>
    <option value="false">Off</option>
</select>
<input type ="button" value="submit" id="btnSubmit" />




<script>    
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {

    var $optionElement = $('#slide-1').val();
    alert($optionElement);
});
</script>
```

I was able to read the values. However, I would like to transform the element
into a slider and at the same time still be able to read the values out of it
[image]

This is my desired slider button that I would like to achieve
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying to do this in css with a checkbox html element.  [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) you can find an easy implementation of how to do this with css.  It might suit your needs.

Html:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Css:

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```